# What tells the Windows installer service that another install is in progress?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

[image: Error screenshot]

The usual fix for this error is to restart the machine, which does, indeed, usually fix the problem. Other solutions for particularly stubborn cases include disabling the installer service, and then rebooting.

But, for the purposes of this question, pretend that this error is occurring on a server or some other system where downtime would be unacceptable. We want to do this without rebooting.

Clearly, there is some data being stored, somewhere, that the installer is checking before throwing this error message. Some flag exists that tells the Installer service that there is another install in progress.

What I am interested in, is **where this data is being stored**.

What *exactly* notifies the installer service that another installation is already in progress?

Comment: As Windows is not open source, I can only speculate the logic may be hidden in Windows Installer (msiserver) service i.e. msiexec.exe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Windows Installer runtime acquires a global mutex with the name `_MSIExecute` during certain stages of an (un)installation. A mutex can only be owned by one thread at a time; for a global mutex, that is one thread on the entire system. Any subsequent attempts to obtain ownership of the mutex will fail until the current owner releases it.

A mutex is a transient object in the Windows kernel. It is not a file on disk at any point. A mutex is automatically released if the current owning thread exits without explicitly releasing it.

This is the same mechanism some programs use to prevent multiple instances of the program from running.

---

To answer the other implied question of *which* process is holding that mutex, you can use tools such as Microsoft/Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or [Handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to find mutexes. In Process Explorer, it should come up in the handle search (Ctrl+F).

Once you've found the process, you'll need to decide what to do with it. The *safest* option is usually to wait, though if it has somehow gotten stuck in an (un)installation step, you might have no choice but to kill it. Of course, killing it could have consequences, e.g. leaving a half-(un)installed program lying around - MSI is supposed to guarantee rollbacks, but those are difficult when the process performing them is killed! It's also difficult to judge whether it's actually stuck, as some steps can take a very long time to complete.

---

See also:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/-msiexecute-mutex
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049193/how-to-prevent-msi-error-another-program-is-being-installed

Comment: If it persists on a restart, isn't that in *Boot* or *Startup* in MSconfig?

Comment: @Mazura A mutex by itself doesn't/shouldn't/can't persist on restart. If `_MSIExecute` is still held post-restart, that means some program has started and acquired the mutex (some post-install tasks do run on startup). In any case, I believe OP is asking if this can be stopped *without* needing a restart - they even say a restart usually resolves their issue.

Comment: Bob - You should change your name to [Bam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dxpMxULHnA) for a day—Bob the answer Bam'r.... they're great!!